# Mouse: Single clicks occasionally register as double clicks

Tags: windows, mouse, sp3, double-click

I have a generic Logitech USB Optical Mouse (couldn't find a model number) and occasionally when I am doing a single click, it registers as a double click instead.

For example, when I click a file once, it opens it rather than selects it. What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: Had the same problem with my Logitech Trackman Wheel, drove me nuts for over a year, could unplug it for a while and use another mouse, then plug it back in and it would work for months until it started the phantom double clicks, finally it did it consistently and on any PC I connected it to, finally convinced me it was the micro-switch in the mouse going bad.

Comment: This can actually be pretty useful for gaming, especially if you spam click a lot. It can help a lot in pvp fights, for example, and can give you an edge over others. Use your mouse as a gaming mouse :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like damage in the button microswitch (I don't know the English term for that).

Some people can disassemble the microswitch and fix it. Or it can be soldered from a different mouse.

Comment: That'd be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this mouse for free so I won't bother fixing it. =)

Answer (score 0):

"Occasionally"? Is there any pattern to whether it happens in a file manager window or in a file? Which OS? If not, then the variation may be due to the user's double click speed. If windows, there'll be a setting in control panel --> mouse --> double click speed. See if lowering that helps.

Comment: No pattern... appears to be very random. I'm running Windows XP Home SP3 on a Samsung N120 netbook. I've left all those settings to default. No problems with my Logitech V550 Nano at all. It's definitely the mouse itself... I just want to know what in the mouse would cause this to happen.

Comment: OK. What about any "read single click as double" setting? Otherwise, perhaps a poor connection/short circuit/dirt type thing inside the mouse?

Comment: How would I be able to check??

Comment: For connection issue, I guess open it up and see! For "read single click as double", look in mouse options in control panel somewhere..?