# Mouse spontaneously started double click on occasional single clicks. Weird behaviour. Cause?

Tags: windows, mouse

My problem is as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/129632/mouse-single-clicks-occasionally-register-as-double-clicks), whereby my left mouse will occasionally register a double click upon a single click. It happens on average (but not exactly) about once every 10-20 clicks. This just started happening today and never occurred before. I've made no hardware or software changes to my PC.

My mouse is a wired, HyperX Pulsefire Surge purchased about 5 months ago, although as will be explained I don't think this has anything to do with the hardware.

I attempted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664179/fixing-mouse-double-click-bug-with-autohotkey) which uses an AutoHotKey script (downloaded most recent AHK version today, v.1.1.33.02 . This is the script:

```
LButton::  
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 100) 
   Return
Send {LButton Down}
KeyWait LButton     ;physical state
Send {LButton Up}
Return
```

Basically, it ignores any double click if it occurs within the integer timelapse from the first click, treating it as a single click instead.

This script seems to be executing flawlessly as it's instructed, but it isn't stopping this spontaneous double click bug. Ie: I can set the delay to even be as large as 500 (ms), and sure enough, any double click that is faster than half a second will not register. So this is evidence the script is working. Yet, once ever 10-20 clicks still, even with this script running, *a single click will spontaneously, and instantly, register as a double click*.

This leads me to believe it's not a hardware (physical mouse) problem. If it was, then surely the software program would filter out the fault as it registers the clicks too quickly.

I'm running Windows 10 and have not made any updates for months, nor have updated any mouse drivers or other drivers for that matter. This behavior is bizarre, and has occurred suddenly within the last 24 hours. As a troubleshooting step, I removed all mouse drivers and scanned for hardware changes to re-install them, and also disabled power saving on USB-Hub. These changes haven't worked.

I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions on what might be causing it?

Comment: It's alarming that you haven't just tried other mouse, did you? Because it really looks like worn out button switch. And AHK can't catch all events 100% reliably, especially in this case.

Comment: @MikhailV I think you might be right. I didn't have another mouse handy and didn't want to buy one, but this looks to be a common issue with the model. I'm curious though how if AHK is registering the mouse click at a low level Windows API, and it specifically instructs it to have a delay, how a hardware double click is passing through still?

Comment: Generally speaking, AHK may not register 100% reliably. If you have a script like `lbutton::return` and nothing else in your script than yes maybe 99.9% will be consumed by AHK, but since you have KeyWait and other code there, this number may be unpredictable. Anyway, I'd start by trying different mice to find the issue.